# Dual SIM Full Active mobile device

Tags: android, dual-sim

I need to develop an app for Android that makes tests on voice calls.
Using a DSFA (Dual SIM Full Active) mobile phone, if the app asks SIM1 to originate a call to SIM2 can the app be noticed that SIM2 is receiving a call from SIM1?